# mySQL error, that I can't find

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm writing because I simply can't find my error, I copied this code from another document and edited some few things, but then I have an error. I'm unable to see what it is.

The following error is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'by,telefon,email) VALUES (987, , , , by, , )' at line 1

And my code is following:

```
 $taelf = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Firma` WHERE `navn` = '$navn'"),0); 
 if($taelf < 1){  
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Firma` (navn,cvr,Adresse,postnr,by,telefon,email)
                   VALUES ($_POST[navn], $_POST[cvr],
                           $_POST[adresse], $_POST[postnr],
                           by, $_POST[nummer], $_POST[email]
                          )"
                ) or die(mysql_error());  
    echo "<div id='success'>Vupti, firmaet er nu oprettet. '$_POST[navn]','$_POST[cvr]','$_POST[adresse]','$_POST[by]','$_POST[postnr]','$_POST[nummer]','$_POST[email]'</div>";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BY` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html). If you are going to name a column with that name you *must* wrap it in ticks:

```
INSERT INTO `Firma` (navn,cvr,Adresse,postnr,`by`,telefon,email)
```

Also see Fabien Warniez's answer which explains that you also need to wrap your string values in quotes.

[Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).
 **You are also wide open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)**

Comment: Oh, i didnt know. I just fixed that, but i end up with another error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' , , by, , )' at line 1

Comment: AND you'll need to quote the values, like this: `INSERT INTO .... VALUES ('". $_POST['navn'] ."', '". $_POST['cvr'] ."', ... etc`
While you're at it, look at [this post about sql injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @user3259244 You're also forgetting the values portion. You have to wrap the `by` after `VALUES` with quotations as well (along with the rest...)

Comment: As the other answer states, you have to add quotes around your values, too, like this:  '$_POST[postnr]', 'by', '$_POST[nummer]'...

Comment: I thought reserved words were, well, reserved. I learn things every day!

Comment: It worked out fine John, yeah im gonna go into all that new stuff soon :-) Thanks for the fast help, how do i select the right answer?

Comment: @user3259244 Just click on the checkmark underneath the vote total

Answer (score 3):

You need to add quotes around your **string** values:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Firma` (navn,cvr,Adresse,postnr,by,telefon,email)
    VALUES ('$_POST[navn]', '$_POST[cvr]', '$_POST[adresse]', '$_POST[postnr]',
    'by', '$_POST[nummer]', '$_POST[email])'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Please note that this should fix your syntax problem, but you really should escape the POST variables.